# Incorrect Permission Assignment For Critical Resources on using @GetMapping, @PostMapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, checkmarx

We are using Spring Boot application to develop an API project. and it has swagger as well.
We are using Checkmarx for the identifying the vulnerabilities in the project.
And in resource methods we are using @GetMapping.
The usage  @GetMapping and @PostMapping is resulting "Incorrect Permission Assignment For Critical Resources"

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@Tag(name = "User Details")
public class UserDataController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = ESAPI.getLogger(UserDataController.class);
@Operation(summary = "Get Details", tags = { "User Details" })
@GetMapping(path = "/v1.3/userData")
public ResponseEntity<UserDataResponseV3> getUserDataV3(
        @RequestParam(value = "changeFromDate", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:Ss.SSS") LocalDate changeFromDate,
        @RequestParam(value = "changeToDate", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:Ss.SSS") LocalDate changeToDate) {
    LOGGER.info(Logger.EVENT_SUCCESS,
            "Request processing for UserDataController.getUserDataV3() execution Started");

    LOGGER.debug(Logger.EVENT_SUCCESS, "userData Criteria-> from " + changeFromDate + " to {}" + changeToDate);

    
    LOGGER.info(Logger.EVENT_SUCCESS,
            "Request processing for UserDataController.getUserDataV3() execution Ended");

    return new ResponseEntity<>(userData, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

In Checkmarx report the below is the vulnerability getting listed.

> A file is created on the file system by path in
> src/main/java/com/test/codes/controller/UserDataController.java at
> line 202 with potentially dangerous permissions.

Comment: Your error says, your test code created the file, also, it is not good idea to have same class name in the test, since you have same package, it will be a hazard.

Comment: Where is exactly the line 202?

Answer (score 0):

I found this question via Google as I'm currently facing the exact same problem.

I analyzed the issue on our end and noticed that Checkmarx seems to mark this as a finding because of the `path` argument in the annotation.

Simply removing the `path` argument, or replacing the `path` argument with `value` (they are aliases for each other) solves the issue.

Results in a finding:

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/v1.3/userData")
```

Results in no findings:

```java
@GetMapping("/v1.3/userData")
@GetMapping(value = "/v1.3/userData")
```

Hope this helps others in the future who are facing the same issues and stumble upon this question.